# Haskell recursion functions and syntax

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I am quite new to haskell and was tasked with creating a function that takes an int and a list of ints, the function would find the inputted ints position and return the value prior to it, ex fn 5 [1,2,3,4,5,6] would return 4. I'm having many problems getting started. First off I keep getting Variable is not in scope errors.

```
fn' ::Int->[Int]->Int
fn' y [] = -1
fn' y (x:xs)
    |y = (head listail) = x 
    |otherwise = listail
    where listail = fn' y (tail)xs
```

Where should I start looking at, and in general are there other things I should or shouldn't do?

Adams code error

```
main.hs:3:31: error:

• Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Int]’
• In the expression: fn y x2 : xs
  In an equation for ‘fn’:
      fn y (x1 : x2 : xs)
        | y == x2 = x1
        | otherwise = fn y x2 : xs
main.hs:3:36: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Int]’ with actual type ‘Int’
• In the second argument of ‘fn’, namely ‘x2’
  In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘fn y x2’
  In the expression: fn y x2 : xs
<interactive>:3:1: error:
• Variable not in scope: main
• Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
```

Comment: What's `findNext'`?

Comment: Tough to say where your issues were since you didn't list the error message, but I guarantee your "Variable is not in scope" is from that `findNext'` typo. N.B. also that `y = (head listail)` is assignment. You want `y == (head listail)` (though `listail` appears to be defined wrong.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pattern matching to grab out two values from the list and compare them.

```
fn :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
fn y (x1:x2:xs) | y == x2 = x1
                | otherwise = fn y (x2:xs)
fn _ _ = -1
```

Note my last case -- this is the fail case, when you can't match the pattern `(x1:x2:xs)`.

Alternatively: `(x1:x2:xs)` could also be spelled `(x1:xs@(x2:_))`. The latter pattern is more complicated to read, but lets you do:

```
fn :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
fn y (x1:xs@(x2:_)) | y == x2 = x1
                    | otherwise = fn y xs
fn _ _ = -1
```

rather than re-joining `x2` and `xs` to recurse.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/Py1PwcpKwTOvREHXTiEaSMeCGECaCyhTqaBRYWhVUeygUWFkFa@pqVADFLK1VagwUgAShlwKWECNQn5JRmpReWZxKlAR2JCKYpBh8UBoq6BryMWVm5iZB2QWlJYElxT55CmoKBRn5JcDKaAqU4VoQx0jHWMdEx3T2P//AQ)

---

As gallais points out in the comments:

Note that this function can take the more polymorphic form `Eq a => a -> [a] -> a`. This is just a change to the type signature

```
fn :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> a
```

This lets you use `fn` with other useful types, i.e. `fn '#' "I'm #1!"` gives `'1'`

Also a better return value here might be a `Maybe Int` (or a `Maybe a` in the polymorphic form), since you'll have some lists that don't contain the search term.

```
fn :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
fn y (x1:xs@(x2:_)) | y == x2 = Just x1
                    | otherwise = fn y xs
fn _ _ = Nothing
```

Comment: I am currently using an online ide for haskell due to limitations at school and I still gave me a "Variable not in scope error" as well as  a "Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Int] -> Int" message. Is this just an error b/c of my ide and if it is what would my original code do?

Comment: @STRAN impossible to tell without knowing what variable you're talking about, what IDE you're using, and what code is running (and how).

Comment: Im using repl.it and I tried to run your code, Ill edit the error message into the post

Comment: @STRAN ahh, I had misplaced parentheses, sorry. It was trying to do `(fn y x2):xs` instead of `fn y (x2:xs)`, and was complaining because `x2` is not of type `[Int]`. Fixed now.

Comment: You may want to discuss corner cases like `fn 1 [1,1,2]`, return a `Maybe Int` rather than an `Int` or even observe that the function can be given a more polymorphic type `Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe a`.

Comment: is `fn 1 [1,1,2]` a corner case? I agree `Maybe Int` is a more natural return value, but I'm not sure it's relevant to this question since OP had already specified the expected failure result.